# oat location is not valid error on android marshmallow

Tags: android

when i test my application on android marshmallow,to open took long time and gives me these errors

```
 oat location is not valid 
/data/user/0/org.linux.ceylon.gpstracker/cache/slice-support-annotations-24.2.1_6ad55f12288d69ec8a892bcf9d346762fe8110c1-classes.dex
     oat location is not valid /data/user/0/org.linux.ceylon.gpstracker/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex
     oat location is not valid /data/user/0/org.linux.ceylon.gpstracker/cache/slice-slice_8-classes.dex
    oat location is not valid /data/user/0/org.linux.ceylon.gpstracker/cache/slice-slice_7-classes.dex
```

and etc...

how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away after I unchecked "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code..." in Android Studio's Preferences.